# Google Chrome takes up very high memory – which is not shown in its Task Manager

Tags: windows, google-chrome, memory

I have opened a single Chrome application with a single tab.

However in the Windows Task Manager (I use Windows hacker) – There are 21 chrome applications seen – each using up to 700 MB of RAM.

The consolidated memory usage in the Chrome Task Manager (Shift-Esc) is ~700 MB.

However the total memory usage from Windows is ~ 1.4 GB !!!!!!!!!!!

I have some extensions running in Chrome – Please find the screenshot below.

What is taking up so much memory????

[image]

Comment: This is how chrome works. One instance launches a lot of processes for various reasons. Webpages, extensions are 2 of the few reasons.

Comment: @LPChip I get it - but how can you explain the 1.4 GB taken up chrome applications when its task manager's shows a memory totals approx 700 MB?

Comment: If you go to the Details tab of Task Manager, it will also show the 1.4GB. Some processes are hidden or initiated using SYSTEM.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I had a similar problem and chrome was taking around 1.2 Gigs of memory.

Here is what you can do, at the extreme top-left right click and go into the task manager menu which will show you the memory consumption stats of the browser. Since your browser is consuming memory around the same size as mine. I am pretty sure you have a lot of extensions running on your browser which is taking up the space.

I had like 6 different adblockers which were taking up the memory and many other extensions for google apps, dropbox extensions etc etc which I disabled to bring down the memory consumption.

Hope this helps.